# jQuery: fadeOut and remove inside bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `.remove` inside `.bind` to close a dialog window. I would like the window (`.another_one`) to `.fadeOut`, but I havent been able to figure out where to place the code.

I've tried adding .fadeOut to various positions in the code and it breaks the functionality (retaining the ability to open the window again without refreshing the page). The code as it stands, where the window closes instantly:

```
$("body").append(the_empty);
the_empty.hide(); 
the_empty.bind("click", function(){
    $(".another_one").remove();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you recreate a small sample of what exactly is not working. As is fadeOut should work fine

Comment: Does your application need to be able to reopen window after it's closed? Doesn't then `.remove()` break your functionality? `.fadeOut()` shouldn't prevent you to reopen the window.

Comment: Yes, the window needs to be able to reopen after it's closed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `remove` is not an animation and is therefor not queued.  It executes immediately and does not wait for the animation to complete.  To get around this, you can simply put the `remove` in the callback of `fadeOut`.

```
$(".another_one").fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer James. I placed your code inside of `the_empty.bind("click", function(){` and fadeOut worked, the issue is I can't open the window after its been closed.

Comment: I wouldn't know without seeing the coded to show it.  Most likely you mean to just `hide` it and not `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing the `dialog` element, you can specify a function to be executed when the [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/dialog/#event-close) event is triggered. Here is an example:

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$('<p>An example</p>').dialog({
    close: function () {
        alert('Closing...');
        $(this).dialog("destroy");
    },
    hide:"fadeOut"
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/DhP9h/2/)